# Possibilities of Datazen server migration

Tags: migration, datazen-server

I know that similar topics have been already raised, but maybe there are some latest news or ideas?

I want to migrate Datazen `users/sources/dashboards` etc. to another server (production one) in a smooth way. I was trying to do that via `backup/restore`, but then I couldn't access the control panel on the target server. I received an error

> 401 unauthorized access.

Maybe I should change something in logs/config files on the destination server?

Any ideas? I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to do this out of the box.  However, the files are quite simple XML, so can be pointed at a different server if you know PowerShell (and work out the correct values from the server).

You will have to re-point the GUID, ServerGUID and ServerURI within the sources.xml file and then rezip (as .datazen).  Providing you have your hubs set up the same, Datazen will then believe the file belongs to your prod environment and you will be able to publish